# Android studio : Could not find method XXXXX(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class

Tags: android-studio, button, onclick, fragment

I have this error when I try to use a **button** with an **android:onClick** from a **fragment** :

[image]

fragment.java :
[image]
fragment.xml :

[image]

But in the design tool, it is well recognized :

[image]

I am aware that the issue is probably somewhere else in the code but I really dont know what to check ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With certitude, the called method by the `onclick` must be on the `activity.java` which launches the `fragment.java` even if you are in this fragment.
But in this case in the `design tool`, in the `onclick` field, your method does not appear.
You need to add and define `android:onClick` manually.
It remains a bit unclear but it works fine even if I probably do not use the right method.